# how to adding mezzanine blog apps to existing django apps

Tags: django, mezzanine

guys
I just installed Mezzanine and would like to use it for a "blogs" section in a Django project. how to sett into my settings.py and urls.py to use mezzanine blog? i want myproject.com/blog using mezzanine blog apps

Comment: Cna you clarify whether you are starting a blank mezzanine project or trying to add it to an existing app?